# How to slice groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have like 40.000 groups after the code:

```
groups=data.groupby('A')
```

I need to subdived them like in sub-groups of 10.000, of course without overlapping and keeping the groupby stucture.
Like group1=groups[0:10000], group2=groups[10000:20000]...
to re-use them in other scripts. How can I do that?

Thank you !

Comment: accept and upvote the solution you found helpfull thats how community stays motivated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in that case you can simply slice using iloc

```
group1=groups.iloc[0:10000,:]
group2=groups.iloc[10000:20000,:]
.
group3=groups.iloc[30000:40000,:]
```

this is when you want to slice according to indexes or number of rows required.

id you want to do it category wise then after performing group b you can simply do this

```
groups=groups.groupby(a).agg()
group1=groups.loc['category 1']
```

code mentioned in question aggregate not mentioned which is not valid refer the link to know how groupby works [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Comment: thank you but it gives me "'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'iloc'"

Comment: do the iloc before performing groupby

Comment: amd groupby without any aggregate in the end is not valid,

Comment: I cannot to that because i want the first 10000 groups not rows, so before i need the groups and then pick up only the first 10.000

Comment: simply do this Groups[Groups['A'].isin( Groups.A.unique()[:10000]  )] this definitely works tested it. just d this donot do any group by vefore doing this just do this on dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're aggregating right afterwards, groupby might be an overkill for this task.

```
data = data.set_index('A')
group_idx = data.index.drop_duplicates()
sub_group_1 = data.loc[group_idx[:10000]]
```

will get you first 10000 groups